# JSON schema child conditional implementation

Tags: json, jsonschema

I've looked through the previous questions and can't seem to find the specific scenario, so apologies if you've seen this question before.

For brevity sake, I have the follow JSON

```
{
  "minimum": 123,
  "charges":[
    {"amount": 123, "billable": 456},
    {"amount": 234, "billable": 456},
  ]
}
```

1. "minimum" is optional initially,
2. both "amount" and "billable" are optional
3. If "amount" is present in any of the objects in the "charges" array, then "minimum" is now required.

The following would be invalid:

```
{
  "charges":[
    {"billable": 456},
    {"amount": 234, "billable": 456}, // amount is present here, so "minimum" needs to be on the root node.
  ]
}
```

The following is valid:

```
{
  "charges":[
    {"billable": 456},
    {"billable": 456},
  ]
}
```

Is this behavior possible? Thank you, brain trust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirements you would need to use the `if` and `required` keywords.

```json
{
  "if": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "charges": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "not": {
            "required": [
              "amount"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "else": {
    "required": [
      "minimum"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, looks like it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But I think that you will need to validate the schema by hand with some kind of function like this:

```
const isValid = ( data ) => {
    /*
        the some: checks if any array elements pass a test

        the operator !!
        converts Object to boolean. If it was falsy (e.g., 0, null, undefined, etc.), it would be false, otherwise, true.
    */

    const mustContainMinimun = data.charges && data.charges.some(charge => !!charge.amount);

    if(mustContainMinimun){
        return !!data.minimum
    }

    return true;

}
```

here you can test the function with your 2 examples:

```js
const isValid = ( data ) => {

    const mustContainMinimun = data.charges && data.charges.some(charge => !!charge.amount);
    
    if(mustContainMinimun){
        return !!data.minimum
    }

    return true;

}

const obj01 = {
    "charges":[
      {"billable": 456},
      {"billable": 456},
    ]
}

const obj02 = {
    "charges":[
      {"billable": 456},
      {"amount": 234, "billable": 456}, // amount is present here, so "minimum" needs to be on the root node.
    ]
  }

console.log( "isValid:", isValid( obj01 ) )
console.log( "isValid:", isValid( obj02 ) )
```